# PHP, Adodb, sqlite3 and AutoExecute returns error 5 (SQLITE_BUSY)

Tags: php, sqlite, adodb-php

I have a little problem. I try execute couple of queries using AutoExecute:

```php
$rows = array(
    array(
        "text" => md5(rand(1,999)),
        "value" => rand(1,999)
    ),
    array(
        "text" => md5(rand(1,999)),
        "value" => rand(1,999)
    ),
    array(
        "text" => md5(rand(1,999)),
        "value" => rand(1,999)
    )
    /* [... and 10 more ...] */
);

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    if ($db->AutoExecute("sometable", $row, "INSERT"))
    {
        echo "Done";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error";
    }
}
?>
```

and I got error code number 5. How to handle multiple queries using Adodb and AutoExecute?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in https://github.com/ADOdb/ADOdb/issues/286:

autoExecute() only handles a single record. Try with

```
foreach($sql as $row) {
    $db->autoExecute('test', $row, 'INSERT');
}
```

As a side note, due to the overhead of autoExecute(), it is probably more efficient do do this with a prepared statement.

Comment: I made a stupid mistake. Not in my script but here. Question is still stands. When I call foreach loop I got SQLITE_BUSY error.